# Are there any good OSS instances of converting an Exception to HTML (C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, formatting, enterprise-library

Working with EntLib 4.1 and want the Exception block to send an email with error information. All that is fine but out of the box I have either the Text or Xml formatter to work with. I would love an Html representation that which brings in other information such as browser, http headers etc. Years ago I wrote one but dont have the source anymore and I came up short on hits on google so I figured I would ask the SO community and see if anyone knew of something floating around out there in the series of tubes that are the interwebs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that ELMAH could be the answer for you? http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Comment: ELMAH is a good example, not exactly what I wanted but I will give you the check mark because it has the need i need to build an HtmlFormatter for EntLib pretty quickly.